# Grails 3 on Bamboo

Tags: grails, bamboo

Is there a way to get Grails 3 to work with Bamboo? The Grails task does not support it. Can I write a custom script or something to handle the war generation such that it can be picked up by a Deployment task?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to add any version of Grails that is not originally provided. For example, if you need a specific minor version of a series, not the latest that Bamboo defaults to, you can simply change the version number in the instructions below. We did this originally with 2.4.4 when Grails 2.4 in Bamboo moved up to 2.4.5.

You will need to be an admin and you will need to configure the instance that your job runs on. Assuming a Linux instance, you can easily add Grails 3:

- Get into Bamboo administration. On cloud, you click on the little top left corn(This is an example of where github flavored markdown's code fencing would be REALLY useful -- for some reason I have to put an extra non-bulleted line in for the indent to become a code block)er hamburger icon, and click Configure.
- Go to Image Configurations
- Click Edit on the appropriate image type.
- Put code similar to the following into the instance startup script

  ```
  #install grails 3.1.1 for fun
  curl -L https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/download/v3.1.1/grails-3.1.1.zip > grails-3.1.1.zip
  unzip grails-3.1.1.zip
  mv grails-3.1.1 /opt/
  ```

  - (the nice thing about grails is the download URL is completely predictable, so replace 3.1.1 with the version number you want -- 3.1.0.RC2, for example):
  - I haven't tried anything similar with Windows images, but I would imagine it is possible.
- Save that script. Doing so brings you back to the image configuration list.
- Now go to Capabilities for that image, and click Add Capability (or scroll to the bottom, either works).
- choose Executable as the capability type. This adds another dropdown to the form.
- Choose Grails from the new dropdown.
- Executable label can be anything, but for consistency, `Grails 3.1.1` looks best
- Path should simply be the path where you put the unzipped `grails-3.1.1` -- `/opt/grails-3.1.1`
- Now you should be able to create a Grails task with Grails 3.1.1 as the version.

One other note to take is that the Gradle build process monkeys a little with the default test report location, so to get your test-app command to pass with Grails 3.0 you will need to change the test report directory. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423613/correctly-specify-test-report-location-for-grails-3-build-on-bamboo/35423680#35423680) for specifics on that.

Also, our Bamboo account has been active long enough that I discovered the JDK 1.8 capability was missing from our capabilities list. I think that simply adding a JDK capability with label `JDK 1.8` and path `/opt/jdk-8` should do the trick, but if that doesn't work, you may need to click Revert to Default Capabilities (and then add back any custom capabilities you had added prior).

Comment: An alternative to the approach above may be to simply use the gradle wrapper in a script. Since Grails 3 has moved to Gradle, this may vastly simplify the setup process. I haven't tried this though, so I cannot speak to its efficacy.