# Correctly specify test report location for Grails 3 build on Bamboo

Tags: grails, gradle, junit, bamboo

I am building a Grails 3 application using Atlassian Bamboo. I've configured the Grails 3 task as explained in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35423050/4905958).

I am having trouble getting Bamboo to find my test reports. On the Grails task type, you can specify if the task produces test results, and if so, where they come from. So I have tried the following:

- Look in the standard test results directory
- Specify custom results directories:

  - `**/*reports/*.xml` (which is the default when you choose Specify...)
  - `build/reports/tests/index.html`

All three produce this error:

> Could not find test result reports in the /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/CSSO-MPA4-JOB1 directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is `build/test-results/*.xml`, as that is where JUnit puts its test reports.

`**/*-reports/*.xml` fails because it is in `-results`.

`build/reports/tests/index.html` fails because, as it says right above the input box:

> Test output must be in JUnit XML format.

I discovered (from somewhere in [this thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-enable-xml-report-output-for-junit/7002/3)) that JUnit is responsible for generating the test results independent of Gradle / Grails, which is how I found they were in an odd place.